# How to find where missing data?

Tags: sql

I have table name: `installs` include 3 column: `log_date`, `product_code`, and `installs`. I want to find out on latest date where product_code is missing data. if product_code has date then return T, or missing data return F.

[image]

Here is some sample data:

```
log_date       product_code  installs
1/1/2018 0:00     a            24
1/1/2018 0:00     c            425
1/1/2018 0:00     d            1
1/1/2018 0:00     g            170
1/1/2018 0:00     h            18
1/1/2018 0:00     i            3
1/1/2018 0:00     k            1
1/1/2018 0:00     l            6
1/1/2018 0:00     m            5

log_date       product_code  installs
1/1/2018 0:00     a            T
1/1/2018 0:00     b            F
1/1/2018 0:00     c            T
1/1/2018 0:00     d            T
1/1/2018 0:00     e            F
1/1/2018 0:00     g            T
1/1/2018 0:00     h            T
1/1/2018 0:00     i            T
1/1/2018 0:00     f            F
```

Comment: Where do we find the list of product codes ?

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using `postgresql`, `oracle`, `sql-server`, `db2`, ...

Comment: what did you try so far?

Answer (score 0):

Use a `cross join` to define the rows and then use `left join` to bring in the information you want.  I am assuming you have a `products` table:

```
select d.log_date, p.product_code,
       (case when i.product_code is null then 'N' else 'N' end) as flag
from (select distinct log_date from installs i) d cross join
     products p left join
     installs i
     on i.product_code = p.product_code and i.log_date = d.log_date
order by d.log_date, p.product_code;
```